# Replace quotation marks only around matches which do not contain ^ or -

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I'm trying to build an expression which would replace quotation marks only from matches that don't include ^ or -

> string = '"Q%LCJ8^1"+"Q%VOD.L"+"Q%LSEG.L[EQ_LIST]MID_PRICE"+"BRT-"'
>
> result = '"Q%LCJ8^1"+Q%VOD.L+Q%LSEG.L[EQ_LIST]MID_PRICE+"BRT-"'

Comment: whats your tries? attempts?

Comment: I am able to capture everything within the quotations with 
\"(.*?)\"
However not sure how to add an exception

Comment: is your `result` the result that you get at the moment? or the expected result?

Comment: It is an expected result unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the possible solutions would be

```
\"([^\-\^+]+)\"
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZHF3nB/1

Answer (score 0):

this regex `"([^\^_+"]+)"` finds in

the source-String

`"Q%LCJ8^1"+"Q%VOD.L"+"Q%LSEG.L[EQ_LIST]MID_PRICE"+"BRT-"`

`"BRT-"` and `"Q%VOD.L"`

not far from what expeced

```
expectedString = '"Q%LCJ8^1"+Q%VOD.L+Q%LSEG.L[EQ_LIST]MID_PRICE+"BRT-"'
```

now a programming language is needed.

the regEx you see also here https://regex101.com/r/z9ERGi/1

Comment: That's indeed quite close to the expected result. When I am using this pattern "([^\-"]+)" within re.sub(pattern, R'\1', text) I get "BRT-" and rest of the matches without quotations. The only bit missing is how to keep  "Q%LCJ8^1" within that result

Comment: if you use PHP look at function preg_match_all